# Spark streaming with JMS - No API

Tags: apache-spark

Is there any API/ way to integrate Spark Streaming with JMS. I am able to integrate with Kafka and Sockets but to integrate with Jms queue or topic I am unable to.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should try calling reciever api in spark. You need to create custom receiver

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-custom-receivers.html

Also check rely from tathagat das who is spark contributor from

www.apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Spark-Streaming-and-JMS-td5371.html

If you need help in detail let me know

Comment: how to use this customer receiver to get Jms message for example how onMessage () method- when a JMS message arrives will be integrated in this code ?

Comment: would you be able to put the sample code in github? and provide a link?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post . Since I am working on something similar. You can use spark jms receiver

[Spark JMS receiver](https://spark-packages.org/package/tbfenet/spark-jms-receiver)